# why Nginx is not allowing to display the images from the filesystem?

Tags: https, proxy, nginx, proxypass, play2-mini

I am working on play2.0 framework (with java) application. In our application we have file upload and file preview feature (all types of files). we are uploading into an filesystem.I am able to display most of documents like  pdf,doc,txt etc file except images . when i am trying to display browser throwing an error message like "This image cannot be display because it contains errors".
I am using NginX reverse proxy for https .I found theat the problem is with Nginx only.Besacuse the all the images and files display is happening without NginX.So I tried with the 'location' directive like bellow:
`location /fileview/ {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.x:443/files/;
   }`
All my file will be uploaded into file folder in the root folder of the play2.0 project.I am sure that i am doing a mistake with proxy_pass,but i don't what to do .

I think that i am doing wrong at location. I got struck with this since 3 days.Can any one help me Please? 
Thanks In Advance.